# issues web scraping https://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/. jupyter notebook frozen at [*]

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

hi so im trying to web scrap https://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/.

i followed https://github.com/patiegm/vgchartzPythonScraper/blob/master/vgChartzScraper.py

and their coding. but when i get to
while data_exists:
page +=

the system freezes, i have updated pykernal and i still cant get it to run.

any advice? or another way to i could scrap the site

I have tried several web scraping instructions but the website seems to be coded really awkwardly. no classes, and hard to determine what is what.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the table to pandas Dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.vgchartz.com/gamedb/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('#generalBody table')

table.tr.extract()
table.tr.extract()

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Pos | Game | Game.1 | Console | Publisher | VGChartz Score | Critic Score | User Score | Total Shipped | Release Date | Last Update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | Tetris | nan | The Tetris Company | nan | nan | nan | 496.40m | 01st Jan 88 | 27th Feb 20 |
| 2 | nan | Pokemon | nan | Nintendo | nan | nan | nan | 480.00m | 28th Sep 98 | 03rd Feb 20 |
| 3 | nan | Super Mario | nan | Nintendo | nan | nan | nan | 400.39m | 20th Jul 83 | 20th Feb 20 |
| 4 | nan | Call of Duty | nan | Activision | nan | nan | nan | 400.00m | 29th Oct 03 | 03rd Feb 20 |
| 5 | nan | Grand Theft Auto | nan | Rockstar Games | nan | nan | nan | 400.00m | 27th Mar 98 | 03rd Feb 20 |
| 6 | nan | FIFA | nan | EA Sports | nan | nan | nan | 325.00m | 15th Dec 93 | 03rd Feb 20 |
| 7 | nan | Minecraft | nan | Mojang | nan | nan | nan | 238.00m | 18th Nov 11 | 08th Feb 20 |
| 8 | nan | Minecraft | nan | Mojang | nan | nan | nan | 238.00m | 18th Nov 11 | 08th Oct 20 |
| 9 | nan | Lego | nan | Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment | nan | nan | nan | 203.22m | 26th Sep 97 | 01st Mar 20 |
| 10 | nan | Assassin's Creed | nan | Ubisoft | nan | nan | nan | 200.00m | 13th Nov 07 | 11th Feb 20 |